# I can't make git diff use opendiff

Tags: git, git-diff, opendiff

I want to use opendiff as default diff-tool for git diff. This used to work but for some reason stopped working.
I'm using a script:

```
echo opendiff $2 $5 > opendiff-git.sh
```

which is set in .gitconfig:

```
[diff]
external = ~/opendiff-git.sh
```

This stopped working for me lately. What is wrong?

Update:
When I cloned a new repository everything worked fine! Strange!

Comment: Is it reporting an error?  Or just giving a regular built-in diff?

Comment: No it's not reporting an error when using git diff it just print the diff in the terminal. I can also use opendiff by itself.

Comment: I have the exact same problem in Mac OS X. Before, opendiff worked great even without setting this shell script. After it stopped working, I added the script and the diff.tool and diff.external options but it still doesn't work. And it does not give an error, just makes a terminal diff. What can be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this question while I was trying to set opendiff as my git diff & merge tool.
Weird thing is that when I used the echo opendiff $2 $5 > opendiff-git.sh to create a script the script did not contain the argument place holders $2 $5 I added them in manually and it started working!

This command

```
echo opendiff $2 $5 > opendiff-git.sh
```

Resulted in opendiff-git.sh file containing

```
opendiff
```

I added the two argument placeholders $2 $5 manually

```
opendiff $2 $5
```

Made the shell script executable as suggested by knittl

```
chmod +x ~/opendiff-git.sh
```

And it works!

Comment: You have to escape the '$' on the command line or the shell triest to find variables with the names '$2' and '$5', which didn't exist so they were substituted with empty string.  Try to run this instead:  echo opendiff \$2 \$5 > ~/opendiff-git.sh

Answer (score 2):

make sure your `opendiff-git.sh` file has its executable bits set:

```
chmod +x ~/opendiff-git.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now specify a default tool using `git config`. To use FileMerge, i.e. `opendiff`, run:

```
git config --global diff.tool opendiff
```

If you view your `~/.gitconfig` file, you should now see:

```
[diff]
    tool = opendiff
```

It should now work.

Comment: does not work on _macOS Sierra_ and _git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)_